# Android provide/sync contacts from app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I would like to save and sync contacts with the phone Contacts. The saved contacts from my app should appear under some syncaccount. If the app is uninstalled, then all these contacts should be removed.

After reading the Android documentation, I have created a SyncAdapter and ContentProvider. The only thing that these two are doing now is creating a account. My ContentProvider is yet a dummy.

[image: Android contact accounts]

The first thing I would like to do is manually saving a contact by using my own sync account. The following code I have found on SO is only creating a phone contact without any link to my sync account.

```
public static boolean insertContact(ContentResolver contactAdder,
        String firstName, String mobileNumber) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                    firstName).build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    mobileNumber)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());

    try {
            contactAdder.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I save a contact from my app under my own syncaccount so you can see my app logo in the Contacts list?

It's kinda hard to find some information about it on internet. Most resuls are about exchanging/modifying existing contacts.

Comment: Hello, how di you create your content provider and linked it to the contacts?

Comment: You have to save your contact by giving a ACCOUNT_TYPE and a ACCOUNT_NAME. Take a look at the answer.

Comment: Yes, but you have to declare a provider in your manifest, no? just setting a string type will do the trick? I will try tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to save a contact under my sync account!

I was so close. It was just this giving the account type and name while doing a insert:

```
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, MY_ACCOUNT_NAME)
            .build());
```